# Wordpress Variable Products

Tags: wordpress

I'm creating a new website for my partners business, however i've stumbled upon an issue that my head can't get around.

Basically, if you take a look at the below address you can see a product with options.

http://www.pollypony.co.uk/product/t-shirts/

However, unless i'm doing it the hard way I want to be able to select a size that has pricing, choose fabric and select if they want short/long sleeve which also has pricing?

Any help would be appreciated?

Comment: I am not sure what you're asking help for

Comment: I can get the first price to show but not the last one that says choose style - 2 options one with a price one?